# How to get the size of an article has been displayed in the mobile web page using java?

Tags: java, selendroid

1. I want to get an total article size that get displayed in the mobile web page using java in selendroid web driver.
2. My mobile page contains an article exactly 21 articles. But, in page view it displays only 10 articles. Next 11 get displayed in the next page, that means, I need to scroll the and see the remaining articles.
3. I have tried with below coding, it prints the size as 10 article only.
4. How can I able to get the total size of an article present in the mobile web page?

> // get articles list
>               List articleLists = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
>                       .visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
>                               .cssSelector(".chTest .media-item")));
>              int s=articleLists.size();
>              System.out.println("size="+s);